# I want to add user's id on the url path or in the address of the page

Tags: python, django, url

i have a url on my page that is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/affiliation/link/10006/".

In the above url I want to add the user id along so that it looks like :"http://127.0.0.1:8000/affiliation/link/01/10006/" something like this, whereas '01' is the user id of the user who uploaded the product.

Below are the files.

views:

```
#Display individual product and render short links for all using pyshorteners
def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
    slink = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" + request.get_full_path()
    shortener = pyshorteners.Shortener()
    short_link = shortener.tinyurl.short(slink)
    return render(request, 'link.html', {"results": results, "short_link": short_link})
```

models:

```
#Product details uploaded
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('link/<int:uid>/', views.link_view, name='link_view')
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want user.id in your path you can add it just like "uid" in your current urlpatterns

```
path('link/<int:user_id>/<int:uid>/', views.link_view, name='link_view')
# and your view signature would be:
def link_view(request, user_id, uid):
```

but if you just need the current user object, it can be obtained from "request" object passed into your view

```
def link_view(request, uid):
    user = request.user
    # ...
```

Comment: when i try this, i get NoReverseMatch at that location.

Comment: "NoReverseMatch" usually occurs when you pass an undefined name in django.urls.reverse() in your view or your template. I suggest you to follow a tutorial (for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01) if you're new to django to understand the whole request to response cycle.